# What does IIS consist of and how does it work?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created and configured websites for some time now, but I never really understood what IIS is.

Is it an executable? A group of executables? Some DLLs? What is its relationship with W3wp.exe?

Is this explained anywhere in MSDN?

Thanks.

**[EDIT]** Ok, it's `inetinfo.exe`. I have found a detailed description here: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp

Comment: w3wp.exe is a web process spawned by IIS for each application pool that you have configured and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS is a server process that hosts web applications in a Windows environment.

Learn about it here: http://www.iis.net/

As I mentioned in the comment above: w3wp.exe is a web process spawned by IIS for each application pool that you have configured and running.

Comment: inetinfo.exe is the main process.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)

> Internet Information Services (IIS) –
> formerly called Internet Information
> Server – is a web server application
> and set of feature extension modules
> created by Microsoft for use with
> Microsoft Windows

It is an exe (InetMgr.exe)

Comment: inetMgr.exe is not IIS, it is the IIS management utility.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=32c54c37-7530-4fc0-bd20-177a3e5330b7 - You are probably thinking of inetinfo.exe

Answer (score -1):

IIS stands for Internet Information Services – a web server for web application, API, web services etc. Current version: 10.0

It is part of operating system and if we are configuring desktop/server for first time then we need to configure in control panel(cmd: appwiz.cpl) –> click Turn windows features on or off –> please checked option “Internet information Services” and next select latest .net framework. It will take few seconds to install. Now you are ready to use IIS. We can access it using inetmgr command in run command. For more, please refer https://bariablogger.in/f/iis-%E2%80%93-a-web-server